# How do I check a child element in protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I need to know how to check a child element of a parent object

I am trying to check that a checkbox in my application is being deselected. All of my checkboxes have the same value in the code. My parent has a 100% unique name. I need to know if there is a way to check that the checkbox for my parent element is deselected without it just checking the first element with the checkbox code.

```
<div ng-repeat="k in model.keys" class="Filter__item ng-scope">
  <a ng-click="toggleSentiment(k)" pt-id="POSITIVE-filter-toggle" 
     class="btn btn-default"> 

    <fa type="far" icon="check-square" 
        ng-class="{'text-success':!model.sentiment[k].on}" 
        class=ng-isolate-scope text-success">

      <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-check-square fa-w-14" 
          aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="far" data-icon="check-square" 
          role="img" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg" 
          viewbox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg>


//for the selected checkbox
icon="check-square"
//for the deselected checkbox
icon="square"

//for my parent
pt-id="POSITIVE-filter-toggle"
```

the `pt-id` is unique, but all the check boxes have same `icon` attribute value.

I can click on the filter using the pt-id but the checkbox is the same everywhere

Comment: Please share the HTML

Comment: <div ng-repeat="k in model.keys" class="Filter__item ng-scope">
    <a ng-click="toggleSentiment(k)" pt-id="POSITIVE-filter-toggle" class="btn btn-default">
        <fa type="far" icon="check-square" ng-class="{'text-success':!model.sentiment[k].on}" class=ng-isolate-scope text-success">
            <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-check-square fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="far" data-icon="check-square" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg>

So basically, I can click on the filter using the pt-id but the checkbox is the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy the only way to check whether the checkbox/radio button is selected or not is via **getAttribute('attributte's name')** but it totally depends on your UI designed by dev team i.e. there should be a flag **selected** with values **true and false**.
So, my opinion is better to check you HTML from browser's Dev tool that is their any kind of flag is present or not. Else check with dev team for what to do with this case.

Also, every HTML tag shows some property attributes in the devtool, here is the image
[image]

But this Attribute "checked:false" you will not be able to fetch it via getAttribute method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector: `parent selector > child selector` to find child element of specific parent.

Then use `getAttribute('icon')` to get the value of `icon` for comparing.

```
element(by.css('a[pt-id="POSITIVE-filter-toggle"] > fa'))
  .getAttribute('icon')
  .then(function(value){
     expect(value).toEqual('square');
  })
```